# Dual monitors in Windows 10 - Only one works at a time

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have two monitors connected to a video card on my Desktop PC which has multiple outputs including two DVI outputs and an HDMI output. I previously had two monitors attached with DVI cables. My new monitors don't have DVI ports, so I got an adapter from DVI to HDMI to use. I have one monitor plugged into the HDMI port and I've tried using the adapter in both DVI ports. In both cases, only one monitor will work at a time. Both monitors are detected, but only one shows output, and the other one will have no options to set for resolution (and displays a message stating it can't read any input and is going into power save mode).

[image: Image showing that both monitors are detected]

[image: Missing settings if the "inactive" monitor is chosen]

I can change which display is working by choosing either "Show only on 1" or "Show only on 2" under the "Multiple Displays" settings. The other two available options, "Duplicate these displays" and "Extend these displays", seemingly do nothing, and revert back to my last choice of the "Show only" options. "Make this my Main Display" is greyed out if I select either monitor. I get the same results attempting to use Windows+P to change how they display.

I'm at a loss as to how to solve this. Previously, it just worked, with the two monitors detecting just fine from the two DVI ports.

This is a Radeon 6950 card and I'm using two Dell U2417H monitors.

My Radeon driver version shows up as 15.301.1901.0 in Device Manager, and a Radeon Software Verison of 16.2.1 in AMD Radeon Settings (I don't know why there are two different values).

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your DVI to HDMI adapter. Some questions: 1)If your primary video card has HDMI & DVI ports, why not use both of them instead of a second video card that could possibly complicate things? 2)You say your second video card has only a DVI port, yet further down you say its HDMI to second card then HDMI to monitor? 3)Please list your video adapter models as that can confirm to use they can support two monitors at once & possibly if certain adapters might not work. If you could give us your monitor models & driver versions they could also help

Comment: Thank you. In the course of research, I've realized that I do only have one graphics card. I was confused. I'm modifying my question to reflect that.

Comment: Updated the info in my question.

Comment: If you ONLY plug in the DVI to HDMI adapter & monitor it works? I believe you confirmed that above, but want to be sure as some adapters are only one way. My experience with this adapter type is that HDMI OUT from PC goes to DVI monitor so unsure if it works in reverse

Comment: Google pictures for this video card seem to imply it has two tiny plugs (Mini-DP, meaning DisplayPort). If it does your monitors said they came with Mini-DP to DP adapter cable

Comment: Ah, got it. The monitors are from work, so I was given a Mini-DP to DP cable and two DP to DP cables. The Mini-DP to DP cable works fine. Still trying to make the daisy-chaining work with the DP to DP cable, but for now, I can run the second monitor with the HDMI connection.

Comment: Added my last two comments as an answer. If it helped you please upvote it. If you believe it solved your issue/question you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ONLY plug in the DVI to HDMI adapter & monitor it works? I believe you confirmed that above, but want to be sure as some adapters are only one way. My experience with this adapter type is that HDMI OUT from PC goes to DVI monitor so unsure if it works in reverse.
Google pictures for this video card seem to imply it has two tiny plugs (Mini-DP, meaning DisplayPort). If it does your monitors said they came with Mini-DP to DP adapter cable